# How to do a UserControl that is Freezable ?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My problem is that I would have to derived both from FreezeObject and from UserControl and multiple inheritance is impossible.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to approach this functionality is to create an interface for the 2nd class to inherit. Lets say the UserControl is the current class and we wan't it to implement the FreezeObject functionality. Now we'll simply add an interface.

```
IGetFreezeObject
{
    FreezeObject GetFreezeObject()
}
```

Let the UserControl implement the interface and let the UserControl return an object that represents the FreezeObject functionality part of the UserControl.

What I see most is that the FreezeObject returned is a simple wrapper around the UserControl that simply passes the FreezeObject function calls straight to the UserControl functions.

If the FreezeObject implements a lot of functionality that you need instead of the UserControl you have to check out how to 'forward' that functionality in you're own wrapper class. This might not be an easy solution.